# How to handle database partitioning in laravel with model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, eloquent

I have table partitioned into say P14, P17, p16 etc. and I am using eloquent  model I want to select the data from this partition.

For this use case I am not getting I should I use partitioning with model and I don't want to use raw query solution.

Is there any way where I can specify the partition  in:

```
$result=ModelName::where(codition)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent model mapping to partition table, for example, table_001, table_002...

```
 $user = new User();
 user->setConnection('table_001');
 $user->name = 'Joe';
 $user->save();
```